# Is it true for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(p_{n})^{1 + \epsilon}}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I'm thinking that if it is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(p_{n})^{1 + \epsilon}}$ diverges, where $p_{n}$ denotes the sequence of prime numbers. According to p-series test, $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 + \epsilon}}$ converges for all $\epsilon > 0$. Thus, I'm thinking that if the same ideas work for prime sequences, and the partial sum still converges. And also I'm wondering if the result will change if we have $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lfloor(p_{n})^{1 + \epsilon}\rfloor} $ 
 Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm thinking that probably it's true for some $\epsilon$ for the first partial sum.

Comment: Your argument shows that the prime version *converges*.  After all, the partial sums are dominated by those for the unrestricted natural numbers.

Comment: @lulu Does it also converge for the floor function version?

Comment: Sure.  Taking the floor at most changes the denominator by $1$, that's not significant as far as convergence goes.

Comment: Note:  you are asking if the series *diverges*.  It does not.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your answer! That helps a lot!

Comment: According to p-series test, $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 + \epsilon}}$ converges for all $\epsilon > 0$.<br>
The start value should be 1 because $\frac{1}{n^{1 + \epsilon}}$ is undefined when $n=0$.

Comment: @Lucenaposition Thank for your comment! I've edited both the title and the content and changed n = 0 to n = 1

Comment: @Miranda you still have used [n=0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763078/is-it-true-for-all-epsilon-0-sum-n-1-infty-frac1p-n1#:~:text=of%20prime%20numbers.-,According%20to%20p%2Dseries%20test%2C,converges,-for%20all) in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Both series $\sum p_n^{-1-\epsilon}$ and $\sum (\lfloor p_n^{1+\epsilon}\rfloor)^{-1}$ converge. The first series converges by the $p$-test, by the comment of user @lulu.

The second series converges because $\lfloor p_n^{1+\epsilon}\rfloor \ge  p_n^{1+\epsilon}/2$ if $n$ is large enough depending on $\epsilon$ since there are infinitely many primes.